# SassError: There is no module with the namespace "math"

Tags: sass

I'm having trouble getting the math SASS library to work in a Vue app. It compiles with Dart Sass, and sass-loader. The Dart Sass version is `1.26.3`, so the math module *should* work.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: There is no module with the namespace "math".

@for $i from 2 through 10 
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) { transition-duration: 300ms + $i * 50ms - 400ms * math.floor($i / 8); }
                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

- Dart Sass: v1.26.3 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)
- Sass-loader: v8.0.2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add

```
@use 'sass:math';
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: why is this not documented straight in https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math!? thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @denns to be fair, it is documented at: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules

Comment: yeah that is where i found it, but originally i endet up in the examples section, where the examples did not work because of this.

Answer (score 13):

What I could recommend you is an automatic (lazy) way - you may use:

```
$ npm install -g sass-migrator
$ sass-migrator division **/*.scss
```

From: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div#automatic-migration

Comment: This won't work for someone trying to fix a scss within vue components for example ...