# There is no module with the namespace "math" Angular 6

Tags: angular, node-sass

At first, I was getting some warnings like:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($scrollview-pager-item-spacing, 4)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

    ╷
144 │             bottom: ($scrollview-pager-offset - ($scrollview-pager-item-spacing / 4));
    │                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\scrollview\_layout.scss 144:50      @content
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\mixins\core\_import-once.scss 12:9  exports()
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\scrollview\_layout.scss 4:1         @import
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\scrollview.scss 11:9                @import
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\all.scss 16:9                       @import
    stdin 3:9                                                                           root stylesheet

Recommendation: math.div($num, ch-pow($x, $n - 1))

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
51 │         $x: math.div(1, $n) * (($n - 1) * $x + ($num / ch-pow($x, $n - 1)));
   │                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\mixins\vendor\color-helpers\_math.scss 51:49      ch-nth-root()
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\mixins\vendor\color-helpers\_math.scss 29:17      ch-pow()
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\mixins\vendor\color-helpers\_contrast.scss 16:56  ch-color-luminance()
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\mixins\_colors.scss 91:12                         contrast-wcag()
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\_variables.scss 210:19                            @import
    node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\all.scss 1:9                                      @import
    stdin 3:9                                                                                         root stylesheet
```

then I opened files and fixed as recommended. Also, as suggested in : [SassError: There is no module with the namespace "math"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330432/sasserror-there-is-no-module-with-the-namespace-math), I installed:

```
npm install -g sass-migrator
npm i sass-migrator
```

But now I'm getting these Errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
                                               ^
      There is no module with the namespace "math".
    ╷
140 │             bottom: ($scrollview-pager-offset - math.div($scrollview-pager-item-spacing, 4));
    │                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\scrollview\_layout.scss 140:49      @content
  node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\mixins\core\_import-once.scss 12:9  exports()
  node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\scrollview\_layout.scss 4:1         @import
  node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\scrollview.scss 11:9                @import
  node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\all.scss 16:9                       @import
  stdin 3:9                                                                           root stylesheet
      in C:\project path..\..\node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\scss\scrollview\_layout.scss (line 140, column 49)
```

in package.json I have:

```
  "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
  "sass": "^1.41.0",
```

Please suggest how to fix error

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to install `node-sass` or `sass` there are angular dependencies and you should use:

```
@use 'sass:math';
```

at top of your file to clear the warning.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install any library. However, `@use 'sass:math'` did not work for me. I had to change it to `@use 'sass:math' as math;`.